# HorizontalScrollView in Spinner: no spinner item selection

Tags: android, spinner, horizontalscrollview

I have a spinner which is made up of rows having one TextView and an ImageView. This worked fine until I decided to wrap the ImageView with a HorizontalScrollView because some images were larger and should be scrollable.

Now, the spinner is still expanded on selection, and the scrolling works like expected. However, I cannot select a spinner item, even not when tapping on the TextView which should not be affected by the introduction of the HorizontalScrollView. ("Cannot select" means: on selection, the spinner is no more shrunken.)

Here goes the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLoknummer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrLok"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```